# Replacing NA's in each column of matrix with the median of that column

Tags: r, matrix, na, median, imputation

I am trying to replace the NA's in each column of a matrix with the median of of that column, however when I try to use `lapply` or `sapply` I get an error; the code works when I use a for-loop and when I change one column at a time, what am I doing wrong?

Example:

```
set.seed(1928)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100*110), ncol = 110)
mat[sample(1:length(mat), 700, replace = FALSE)] <- NA
mat1 <- mat2 <- mat

mat1 <- lapply(mat1,
  function(n) {
     mat1[is.na(mat1[,n]),n] <- median(mat1[,n], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
)   

for (n in 1:ncol(mat2)) {
  mat2[is.na(mat2[,n]),n] <- median(mat2[,n], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: `matrix` objects are vectors with dimensions. `lapply` will loop over every single value in the matrix instead of the columns.

Comment: If you're feeling super lazy and don't want to write your own function, you can use `na.roughfix` from the `randomForest` library. It automatically replaces all NA values with median/mode depending on whether it is numeric/factor.

Comment: @Jonno Bourne, if you're asking about dataframe not matrices, please edit your reproducible example to give a dataframe. Mind you that would invalidate the accepted solution...

Comment: @smci The question doesn't mention dataframes and was successfully answered, using matrices a year and a half ago, can you clarify your comment.

Comment: @JonnoBourne: I know it was answered, that's my point, this vaguely-worded question was **[being (wrongly) cited as a canonical answer elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362281/how-do-i-change-na-into-column-median#comment75726792_44362281)** for replacing NAs in dataframes. The vague title didn't make clear that it wasn't applicable to dataframes, so the title needed editing. (It turns out there is no canonical answer for "replacing NAs in dataframes by column medians". So we need to prevent questions on that topic wrongly being closed-as-duplicate into this one. Ok?

Comment: Given the context your edits are sensible, if you'd had deleted your comment after making them it would have been less confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest vectorizing this using the `matrixStats` package instead of calculating a median per column using either of the loops (`sapply` is also a loop in a sense that its evaluates a function in each iteration).

First, we will create a `NA`s index

```
indx <- which(is.na(mat), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Then, replace the `NA`s using the precalculated column medians and according to the index

```
mat[indx] <- matrixStats::colMedians(mat, na.rm = TRUE)[indx[, 2]]
```

Comment: I actually realized I wanted to do it on a data frame, but I could convert to a matrix and perform this operation then convert back, thanks.

Comment: In most cases, you have a numerical data set, it is much more efficient to work with a matrix rather `data.frame`. Even when you use a simple loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sweep`:

```
sweep(mat, MARGIN = 2, 
      STATS = apply(mat, 2, median, na.rm=TRUE),
      FUN =  function(x,s) ifelse(is.na(x), s, x)
    )
```

EDIT:
You can also drop in `STATS=matrixStats::colMedians(mat, na.rm=TRUE)` for a little more performance.

Answer (score 1):

`lapply` loops over a list. Do you mean to loop over the columns?

```
matx <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(mat1)), function(n) {
  mat1[is.na(mat1[,n]),n] <- median(mat1[,n], na.rm = TRUE)
})
```

though that's essentially just doing what your loop example does (but presumably faster).

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly get there easier via conversion to `data.frame` and back to `matrix` as a result, using `vapply`:

```
vapply(as.data.frame(mat1), function(x)
   replace(x, is.na(x), median(x,na.rm=TRUE)), FUN.VALUE=numeric(nrow(mat1)) 
)
```