# How do I change NA into Column median

Tags: r

A data frame contains 123 columns, 
and each columns have at least 1 NA value.

I want these NA values to be raplaced into column median.
because there are so many columns, i cannot write a code using each column name.

so i tried to use 'apply' to solve this but it didn't work.

```
data2[-1]<-lapply(data2[-1],function(x)x - median(x,na.rm=TRUE))
```

it says it doesn't work since it is data frame, not numeric.

Comment: Please provide example data as plain text, not images, so users can copy/paste. You can paste the output from `dput(data2)` or if large, `dput(head(data2))`.

Comment: **This is not a duplicate, so don't VtC.** @RonakShah: the question and answer you cite is about matrices not dataframes, although the asker had meant to ask about about dataframes, but they didn't. I retitled it *"Replacing NA's in each column of matrix with the median of that column"*. So we do actually do need a canonical example for a dataframe. Might as well use this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  df[is.na(df[,i]), i] <- median(df[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: i have 123 columns i can't do $ function on my code that is too unefficient

Comment: does my update work?

Comment: well it made another error, but at least using 'for' like C gives me some idea. thx for that.

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: always welcome ))

Comment: May I ask something?

Comment: of course,what's up?

Comment: I put the same code for my new data.frame that contains <NA> instead of NA and this code stops working. it says they needs digital data.

Comment: should I fix the data.frame so that it gets NA than <NA> or should i fix the code you wrote?

Comment: I think you'd have to include some lines to get it work. Maybe fix `<NA>` to `NA`? You can use `gsub()` or other options.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na.aggregate`

```
 library(zoo)
 j1 <- sapply(df1, is.numeric)
 df1[j1] <- na.aggregate(df1[j1], FUN = median)
```

Comment: well, that didn't work.

Comment: @Equinox  can u be specific instead of `that didn't work`

Comment: console says : In mean.default(x[!is.na(x)]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: @akrun I expect it's the usual have to assign the output `df1 <- na.aggregate(...)`

Comment: @Equinox  That is because you are applying for the whole data.  I assumed that you had only numeric columns.  In this case, apply it to selected columns

Comment: @Equinox  Try it now

Comment: @akrun k, i ll try it.

Comment: @Equinox  I tried it on your dput example, it is working for me

Comment: @akrun no error found, but NA value didn't change

Comment: @Equinox  Then, please check whether the `NA` is real NA or `"NA"`

Comment: @akrun yepp, you got it. Checking with is.na, all NA is false. I guess i should change "NA" into real NA

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map2_df`

```
library(purrr)
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(2, NA, 9), c = c(NA, 3, 5), d = c(0, 4, NA))
purrr::map2_df(df, purrr::dmap(df, median, na.rm = TRUE), function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(x), y, x))
```